# Seaborn - Timeseries line breaks when hue is added

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I am having trouble plotting a timeseries plot using seaborn. By adding `hue` to the plot the timeseries plot breaks. I can't figure out why the time series plot break in between and how can I stop dates from overlapping.

The code to replicate the issue is below:

```
test_data = {'Date':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09'],
             'Price':[20, 10, 30, 40, 25, 23, 56],
             'Kind': ['Pre', 'Pre', 'Pre', 'Pre', 'Current', 'Post', 'Post']}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
test_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test_df['Date'])
sns.lineplot(data=test_df, x="Date", y="Price", hue='Kind')
```

How can I fix the line break and dates overlapping?

Comment: Can you describe the output you expect?  The dates are disjoint for the three "Kind" categories, and the "Current" category only has one point, where a line plot isn't meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `style` and `markers` arguments to handle the isolated point with "Kind" == "Current":

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
sns.lineplot(data=test_df, x="Date", y="Price", style='Kind', markers=['o', 'o', 'o'], hue='Kind')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

which displays the plot:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell how to fix the overlapping dates on x-axis?

Comment: use ```plt.xticks(rotation=45)``` (or try rotation=90) to rotate the axis labels

Comment: update: added code to fix the xaxis labels per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705581/rotating-xticks-causes-the-ticks-partially-hidden-in-matplotlib